# How to avoid the edit mode on a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I searched for an answer here in SO, but I couldn't find one.

I have a gridview like this one:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvSubEventos" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Descrição" DataField="Descricao">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data" DataField="data" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}">  
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Opção" EditText="Editar" ShowEditButton="true">
        </asp:CommandField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If the user clicks on edit, another form is opened (above of the grid, in the same page) for editing.

The problem is: When the user clicks on the edit button for the first time, everything works. But if he clicks on the edit button again, after the postback of the first edit, the row in the gridview becomes editable.

How can I always avoid edit mode on gridviews?

Comment: opens a form in the same page- meaning is it inside an update panel? this would avoid refreshing the page. How about an hyperlink column? does it produce the same behavior as well?

Comment: It just has a form above the grid and, when the user clicks on edit, the form is populated and setted to visible in row editing event. Can you give me an example with hyperlink column, I don't know pretty much about it. :)

Comment: Sure. My first suggestion would be to use an update panel which enables partial refreshing. In your case show a form without posting back. Its simple and straightforward, here is the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx . The second option is to change your column type to <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Opção" /> this is useful if you open the form in a new page which is not what you would want to do I believe.

Comment: you still need the postback to obtain the data to populate the edit form

Comment: Thank you both for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the button provided in the command field you will trigger the editing ability of the gridview and the gridview expects you will be using embedded editing.  Without getting  into too much detail all you should have to do at the bottom of the RowEditEvent is set `gdvSubEventos.EditIndex = -1` this should take the gridview out of edit mode.

To avoid the gridview from ever entering editmode at all - disable edit in the command field then
add an edit button to bring up your own form:

1. Add a `<asp:ButtonField>` to the column list
2. Convert it to a template field.

In the GridView RowDataBound event

1. Find the button control
2. Assign it's CommandName to something like "MyEdit"
3. Assign it's CommandArgument the row index so you know which row was selected.

When you select this button it will trigger the button's CommandEvent, not the GridView, so you need the row index reference to grab the data you need from the Gridview to populate your fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both suggestions. I'll use the first one now (gdvSubEventos.EditIndex = -1), but thanks for explaining in the way I asked too. :)